# Build 3 distinct sections in HTML body tag

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to set up the body of my website so that it's composed of three sections - a main section (for a slideshow/image), a mid-section (white background), and a footer (gray background). How would I go about doing this? So far, I have tried extending a tutorial for making a simple footer to allow me to add a third section. My HTML and CSS snippets are below:

index.html

```html
<body bgcolor="#212121">
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="content">
            <p>text</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="midsection"><div id="mid-content">Mid</div></footer>
    <footer id="footer"><div class="footer">Footer</div></footer>
</body>
```

styles.css

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    min-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

  #wrapper {
    background-color: #212121;
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    margin-bottom: -300px; /* the bottom margin is the negative value of the footer's total height */
  }
  
  #wrapper:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 300px; /* the footer's total height */
  }
  
  #content {
    height: 100%;
  }
  
  #midsection {
    height: 300px; /* the footer's total height */
    margin-bottom: -100px;
  }

  #midsection:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 100px;
  }
  
#mid-content {
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    height: 284px; /* height + top/bottom paddding + top/bottom border must add up to footer height */
    padding: 8px;
  }

/* main image section (wrapper) + mid section */


#footer {
    height: 100px;
}

#footer-content {
    background-color: #808080;
}
```

Ideally, I'd like the midsection to be 300px, and the footer to be 100px.

Comment: I'm confused, what's the problem? How is it not working? I see some errors in your html. Is that what you're referring to? Or are you having trouble adding the third section?

Comment: There is a gap that's left after the midsection (white), but it's only the background color, not the gray that I chose to be for the footer (#808080). It's also not 100px high.

Comment: Note that `bgcolor` has been obsolete for several years.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

there were a bit of errors in the html. Remember to close html tags correctly. Hope this helps.

html:

```
<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="content">
      <p>text</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="midsection">
    <div id="mid-content">Mid</div>
  </div>

  <footer id="footer">
    <div class="footer">Footer</div>       
  </footer>
</body>
```

css:

```
html, body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    min-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #212121;
}

  #wrapper {

    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    margin-bottom: -300px; /* the bottom margin is the negative value of the footer's total height */
  }

  #wrapper:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 300px; /* the footer's total height */
  }

  #content {
    height: 100%;
  }

  #midsection {
    background-color: white;
    height: 300px; /* the footer's total height */
    margin-bottom: -100px;
  }

  #midsection:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 100px;
  }

#footer {
  background-color: #212121;
  height: 200px;
}
```

Comment: Ah, I see now. Much appreciated.